# different app name for iphone-ipad

Tags: xcode, app-store

We have uploaded an app to the appstore with the name "appName" . its for Ipad only.
We would like to upload the same app for Iphone only.

I will create a new app to the iphone . with a new bundle id etc.
can we use the same name for the app? or will itunes connect would not allow that ?

What usually devs do about that ?

I couldnt find a clear answer for that- here .

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to say, but you can not do this. iTunes Connect checks your app name when creating a new ITC app to make sure the name hasn't already been used. This is usually handled by devs making the iPhone version first then naming the iPad version something else

(ex. Angry Birds = iPhone,  and Angry Birds HD = iPad).

However, you can use the same name as your iPad app in your apps "Bundle Display Name" in your info.plist file. This will allow you to make your iPhone and iPad apps have the same name on your customers devices.